# VIM: What's the quickest way to return from typing :w<enter> in insert mode?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I forgot to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return to command mode and enter `:w<enter>` in some line I was editing. So I get the following:

```
some line of code:w
    I was typing
   ^ cursor position
```

So what I do is pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or something similar.

Someone has a shorter/better/quicker way of doing this?

Comment: You can map `:%s/w:$//` to a key and use it whenever you mis-typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extra `:w<enter>` is the only insertion in that place I use <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> (undo).

If not it's just as long as yours but depending on personal preferences/habits it *might* be faster: <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (join) + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (delete current char).

Technically the longer sequence can be [saved as a macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) and then invoked with just <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>@</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> (where `key` corresponds to the register in which the macro was saved) - but I just couldn't get the macros into my habits :)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd>

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>: normal state for one command

<kbd>u</kbd>: undo

Note: this might undo more than you want depending on how much you changed.

Comment: Worked but I didn't understand why or what C-o does. I couldn't find help for C-o. Only for C-O. I imagine they're different commands. I can I read the help for it ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Use: `:h i^o`

Answer (score 1):

With `set backspace=2`, you should be able to just press Backspace three times.

This is the same as `set backspace=indent,eol,start`, `eol` being the most important, it allows you to backspace over newlines.

See [Vim | options | backspace](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backspace') or `:help 'backspace'` (note the single quotes) for more details

Comment: how can I read the help for set backspace so I can educate myself on the vim option ? "help set" doesn't have a backspace option. "help set backspace" doesn't work.

Comment: I found it. It's on :help set then Ctrl-] in the link to "options-list" on the top of the page.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira If you type Ctrl-D when a :help line is partially entered, vim will list the possible auto completions.  Can be very handy when you're not quite sure of the name of the topic you need help with.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira `:help 'backspace'` or `:help bs` also work.  Note the single quotes in the first one.